# Networking activity for 36 people

Tags: combinatorics

I need to develop a speed networking activity for 36 people in which the participants will be seated at 6 tables with 6 people each.  I'm trying to come up with the most efficient use of time and least number of rounds to ensure each person sits at a table with all 35 other participants just once.  I'm thinking that there would need to be a minimum of 7 rounds (i.e., each person meets 5 new people per round), but I cannot seem to develop a seating chart that ensures that no one sits at a table with someone they have previously sat with in a previous round.

I'm open to changing the number of people per table (e.g., 9 tables of 4) and doing more rounds if that would make solving the problem easier.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The easiest way is of course having only two people meet on a table for all possibilities but I don't think you want that. What I think you want is a BIBD(36,k,1) with k>2 and I am not sure whether that even exists.

Comment: Are tables of varying sizes acceptable?

Comment: Thanks Shahab.  Yes, we could vary the sizes of the tables.  So maybe some tables would have 6 people in round 1, 5 people in round 2, etc.

Comment: Is 3, 4 people per table acceptable? (for in that case the answer is yes; see Lemma 3.2 of http://www.people.imise.uni-leipzig.de/ernst.schuster/Schuster2013.pdf )

Comment: In case of 5,6 people per table also the answer is known. I cannot seem to access the relevant paper though: F. E. Bennett, C. J. Colbourn and R. C. Mullin, Quintessential pairwise balanced designs.